# Room finder using closest Beacon device

Tags: android, beacon

I have 10 beacon device and 10 room. Consider 1/Room and i want to know currently where i am?
For this : already use `mBeconManager.setRangeNotifier` and arrange beacon list in desc order on "Distance" basic.
And display room as per less distance.
But the process is very slow.

Beacon : eddystone Beacon
Platform: android
Lib: Altbeacon

Is there any other best way for this scenario or example? Can i use `mBeconManager.addMonitorNotifier method?`

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it sounds like you are taking the right approach by sorting the results of `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` callback.

However, you should be aware that the `beacon.distance` estimate is are based on a running average of all the RSSI readings received in the past 30 seconds, which may be too long of an averaging time for your use case.  **You can make the distance estimates be based on a shorter 5 second averaging interval** with code like below:

`RunningAverageRssiFilter.setSampleExpirationMilliseconds(5000l);`

However, if you do this, be warned that this will increase the "noise" on your distance estimates.  To counteract this as much as possible, configure your beacons to advertise as much as you can, at least at 10Hz.

Read more [here.](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/distance_vs_time.html)